# Terraform multi for loops

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I need to use multiple for loop in tf. Here is my code

```
data "oci_identity_availability_domains" "ad" {
          compartment_id = var.tenancy_ocid
        }
    
output ad {
      value = data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ad.availability_domains[*].name
    }
```

---

output of ad:
ad = [
"abi:PHX-AD-1",
"abi:PHX-AD-2",
"abi:PHX-AD-3",
]

---

my json file:

```
{
    "compute" : [
        {
        "service" : "standard-e3-core-ad-count",
        "value" : 10000
        },        
        {
        "service" : "standard-e3-memory-count",
        "value" : 10000
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to use ad in the availability_domain

```
 local.info = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/info.json"))

data "oci_limits_limit_values" "count" {
    for_each = {
      for index, value in flatten([
        for name, value in local.info : [
          for i in value : { name : name, service : i.serice }
        ]
      ]) : index => value
    }
  
    compartment_id      = var.tenancy_ocid
    service_name        = each.value.service_name
    name                = each.value.limit_name
    **availability_domain =  { I need to run this for all 3 AD}**
  }
```

I'm stuck on availability_domain. The value will be one or 3. It's based on the **data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ad.availability_domains[*].name**. Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the code? Any errors?

Comment: Also what is `local.info`?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for looking at the questions. I recently joined StackOverflow and learning things. For some reason, I'm unable to edit the question. local.info is basically the JSON file 

`info =  jsondecode(file("${path.module}/info.json"))`

Comment: Actually, I need to run the same data resource block for each AD. That's where I'm locked. I ran out of ideas  :(

Comment: I Apologize if the question is not understandable. I can submit a new question

Comment: That's fine. Let me have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you can create a **flattened** data structure, for example:

```
locals {
    ad_info_product = merge([
          for ad in data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ad:
            {
              for compute in local.info["compute"]: 
                  "${ad}-${compute.service}" => {
                      ad = ad
                      service = compute["service"]
                      limit =  compute["value"]
                  }
            }
        ]...) # please do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then:

```
data "oci_limits_limit_values" "count" {

    for_each            = local.ad_info_product
  
    compartment_id      = var.tenancy_ocid

    service_name        = each.value["service"]
    name                = each.value["limit"]
    availability_domain = each.value["ad"]
}
```

Comment: Sure @marcin. I'll def try it out and let you know.

Comment: @Datta Probably you will have to modify it, as your question contains things such as `limit_name` which are never defined.

Comment: I just tried with the above code and it looks like `{ad}-${compute} is null or missing something

Comment: `  on local.tf line 18, in locals:
  18:       "${ad}-${compute.service}" => {

Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.`

`Error: Invalid template interpolation value

  on local.tf line 18, in locals:
  18:       "${ad}-${compute.service}" => {

The expression result is null. Cannot include a null value in a string
template.`

`Error: Invalid template interpolation value

  on local.tf line 18, in locals:
  18:       "${ad}-${compute.service}" => {

The expression result is null. Cannot include a null value in a string
template.`

Comment: @Datta it's not possible to get such error based on data in question. This means that your question is not representative of your real code and its unlikely anyone will be able to help you in that case.

Comment: thanks @Marcin. Maybe my logic is incorrect. I'll come up with other ideas. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I forgot to ask. Could you help me to understand why we need ...  `...) # please do NOT remove the dots`

Comment: @Datta Dots change `merge([a,b,c]...)` into `merge(a,b,c)`. https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments